# Strange "Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function" error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a simple function.

```
function assify(ass) {
    window.location.href(ass);
}
```

The parameter I'm running into it is `assify?id=2`

I keep getting an error though (`Uncaught TypeError: String is not a function`)

What's going wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious, is this your actual function or a humorous rewrite?...

Comment: Hah, believe it or not, this is the actual function. The whole script detects adblock (that works just fine, I've tried it without that code) and it sets the user's status to "ass", which publicly humiliates them on their profile.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear IMO. What confused you?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm still fairly new to JavaScript and I don't really know how to read errors yet.

Comment: OK. This message means that you tried to treat a string as a function, which means you tried to *call* something that is not a function. There is only function call here, which is ` window.location.href(ass)`. Hence `window.location.href` is not actually a function, it's a string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`href` is a property and not a method.

`window.location.href = ass;`

Comment: No problem. You can check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) for more on the `location` object.